# Gather Client Domain from Rails API GET Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, get, http-headers

What is the easiest way to capture the domain of a client request on a Rails API?

Example:

If I use https://www.hurl.it/ to post a GET request to:

https://staging.mysite.com/api/v1/products?access_token=7b9f3cddd3914a6f45fa692997fe6dc9

How do I capture that the request is coming from `hurl.it`? I've tried:

- `request.host`
- `request.url`
- `request.referer`
- `request.headers['origin']`

I need this since I check the access token and that the request is coming from the domain that the access token is registered with.

API Controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ApiController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json
      before_filter :restrict_access

      private

      def restrict_access
        api_app = ApiApp.find_by_access_token(params[:access_token])
        binding.pry
        head :unauthorized unless (api_app && (api_app.request_origin.include? request.host.split('?').first))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rails version: 4.2

Comment: Basically you can't count on any of the above to be present or accurate. Many clients do not send HTTP_REFERRER or CORS origin headers. Spoofing the headers is also trivial. Don't rely on them for security.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sticking with the IP address:

```
head :unauthorized unless (api_app && (api_app.request_origin == request.env["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"] ||= request.env["REMOTE_ADDR"]))
```